# Adding Scrollviewer in StackPanel

Tags: wpf

How can i add scrollviewer in stackpanel dynamically, Stackpanel already contain a child element dynamically

Comment: You put it in there and set the visibility of the scrollbars to "auto", then you add controls to it.  Also, you want to be using an ItemsControl and not a stackpanel if you're adding things dynamically to it.  You're coding WinForms in a WPF application.  There are much easier and better ways of doing this now (ItemsControl + DataTemplate + ObservableCollection<T> = no work).

Comment: @H.B.: Eh, it really wasn't worthy of an answer.